# delete data only between may 6 and may 18, 2022

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with `CLIENT_CONTACT` data, where there is call data from 2020 to today.

How can I delete data only between May 6 and May 18, 2022, did I write correctly?

```
DELETE FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
WHERE rep_date >= TO_DATE('06.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') AND rep_date <= TO_DATE('18.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Comment: And what is the problem in your code ?

Comment: OK, alternatively use `DELETE client_contact WHERE rep_date BETWEEN date'2022-05-06' AND date'2022-05-18'` if `rep_date` is a DATE type column with no time portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> did I write correctly?

Maybe.... in Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and it **ALWAYS** has those components; however, many client applications used to access the database will default to not showing the time component and only show the date component (but the time component still exists even if it is hidden).

You can change those client applications to show the entire date/time. For SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, you can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

What you have written is the equivalent of:

```sql
DELETE FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
WHERE  rep_date >= TIMESTAMP '2022-05-06 00:00:00'
AND    rep_date <= TIMESTAMP '2022-05-18 00:00:00'
```

As you can see, if there are any rows with between `2022-05-18 00:00:01` and `2022-05-18 23:59:59` then they will not be deleted.

If your `rep_date` column only contains time components at midnight then your code will work.

---

If you do want to delete all the rows from any time on `2022-05-18` then you need to use:

```sql
DELETE FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
WHERE  rep_date >= TO_DATE('06.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
AND    rep_date <  TO_DATE('19.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

You could also write it using `DATE` literals:

```sql
DELETE FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
WHERE  rep_date >= DATE '2022-05-06'
AND    rep_date <  DATE '2022-05-19'
```

or `TIMESTAMP` literals:

```sql
DELETE FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
WHERE  rep_date >= TIMESTAMP '2022-05-06 00:00:00'
AND    rep_date <  TIMESTAMP '2022-05-19 00:00:00'
```

Or, if you want to pass in `18.05.2022` then you can add a day:

```sql
DELETE FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
WHERE  rep_date >= TO_DATE('06.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
AND    rep_date <  TO_DATE('18.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

or

```sql
DELETE FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
WHERE  rep_date >= TO_DATE('06.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
AND    rep_date <  TO_DATE('18.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1
```

---

You could also use your code but wrap `rep_date` in the `TRUNC` function to truncate the time component back to midnight:

```sql
DELETE FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
WHERE  TRUNC(rep_date) >= TO_DATE('06.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
AND    TRUNC(rep_date) <= TO_DATE('18.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

However, that would not be able to use an index on the `rep_date` column and you would need to use a function-based index on `TRUNC(rep_date)` so it is probably better not to use this method and to get into the habit of using date ranges directly on the column if you can.